# .htaccess rewrites not working after migration from Windows server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, so I have been developing a site for my employer in a subfolder of one of their other live sites. The URL structure in development was `http://our-live-site.net/our-dev-site.com/index.php`. The development server is running on Windows and the new server I've just migrated it to is a *nix Apache server. I'm not quite sure whether this is an issue with not having the extra directory in front or if it is a Windows/Linux difference in how they parse the .htaccess file. I'm inclined to believe the former rather than the latter after doing a bit of research on the matter. I have only 3 rules in my .htaccess file and I've isolated the problem to the last two, the rewrites.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^(inc/ajax|inc/pages|js|fonts|moving-tips)($|/) - [L]

->    RewriteRule ^(.*).php template.php?page=$1 [NC]
->    RewriteRule ^(.*).php template.php?location=$1 [NC][QSA]
    </IfModule>
```

What I need to do is pass all requests to say `http://new-site.com/some-page.php` to `http://new-site.com/template.php?page=some-page`. I also need to keep the option of capturing another `$_GET` var for our location pages (they use a different template), hence the `RewriteRule ^(.*).php template.php?location=$1 [NC][QSA]` after the first rewrite. I have a feeling that I am overlooking something really simple with this, mainly because of the... well simplicity of the rules. Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure this is just an issue of having fresh eyes look at this.

Comment: And your exact problem is... what? What are these rules doing now that you don't want?

Comment: Well, when I echo back the content of `$_GET['page']` it always comes back as 'template'. So apparently the rule is forming some kind of loop and always rewriting as `template.php?page=template` instead of say `template.php?page=about-us` when I try to access `http://new-site.com/about-us.php`

Comment: Yes, unless you terminate rewriting with `[L]` any rewrite rule which matches will trigger and rewrite. Your first rule will turn /blah.php into `template.php?page=blah`, and the second rule will trigger, extract `template` and turn it into template.php?location=template`.

Comment: But if I add the last-rule flag  to the second rewrite it will not add the second `$_GET` var to the end. Is there some other way around this? And if so why would these rules work on the dev server just because the site was located in a sub directory?

Comment: Actually I just noticed if I comment out the last rule it still does the same thing i.e. `$_GET['page']` is still showing 'template'. Strange...

Comment: what second get var? You're not capturing get vars, just the name of the script. If you want to figure out why the results worked on the dev server, turn on rewrite logging at a decently high level (5+, I think), which'll show you the exact rewriting sequence and all intermediate rewrite steps. Compare the old server's log to the new server's log.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4582/discussion-between-k4t434sis-and-marc-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/template.php
RewriteRule ^(.*).php template.php?page=$1&location=$1    [NC,L]
```

to replace both of those RewriteRules

What's happening is that when apache rewrites, it redirects internally and the rewritten path is passed BACK through all the rules, only stopping when the rewritten path (not query string) is the same as the unrewritten path.

Comment: Jon Lin, Thanks! That's got it.
Marc B, thank you also, I'm still new to using .htaccess and guys like yourself are helping me learn all the time :]